# Evaluation allows for combinations whose operators are compound expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheme, lisp, sicp

I find the amazing power of scheme in [sicp](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_1.1.4)

> Exercise 1.4.  Observe that our model of evaluation allows for
>   combinations whose operators are compound expressions. Use this
>   observation to describe the behavior of the following procedure:

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC scheme
(define (a-plus-abs-b a b)
  ((if (> b 0) + -) a b))
(a-plus-abs-b 9 4)
 #+END_SRC

 #+RESULTS:
 : 13
```

I try to mimic it but have no ideas how to deal with symbol operators

```
In [13]: 1 eval("+") 1                 
  File "<ipython-input-13-74042a5242a6>", line 1
    1 eval("+") 1
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [14]: 1 exec("+") 1                 
  File "<ipython-input-14-deabdb544acb>", line 1
    1 exec("+") 1
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a solution to use the symbol operator "+" directly as the scheme does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python we can't pass `+` or `-` directly and we need to wrap them in functions, because they are *operators* and not *procedures* as in Scheme, and hence need to be treated differently by the interpreter.

However, we can do a pretty straightforward translation of the Scheme code to Python, simply by importing the correct operators from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/operator.html) module, and invoking them as any normal function:

```
from operator import add, sub

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    return (add if b > 0 else sub)(a, b)

a_plus_abs_b(9, 4)
=> 13
```

The `operator` module "exports a set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python". Another (less efficient) alternative would be to use `lambda`:

```
my_add = lambda x, y: x + y
my_sub = lambda x, y: x - y

def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    return (my_add if b > 0 else my_sub)(a, b)

a_plus_abs_b(9, 4)
=> 13
```